# ValueError: `validation_split` is only supported for Tensors or NumPy arrays, found following types in the input: [<class 'int'>,

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I've tried making both X and y as numpy array via

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array(X)
y = np.array(y)
```

but did not work, here's my full code for training via alexnet, Everything seems to work until the model.fit in which throws off the error code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization
import pickle
import numpy as np

X = pickle.load(open("X.pickle","rb"))
y = pickle.load(open("y.pickle","rb"))

X = X/255.0


########

##################

#START: ALEXNET (SPECIFIC CODES)
- - - - -

##END: ALEXNET (SPECIFIC CODES)

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
             optimizer="adam",
             metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.1)
```

Comment: please print out X,shape and y.shape

Comment: Convert your inputs to Numpy array before passing it to the model. `x=np.array(x)` and `y = np.array(y)`. Thanks!